# set direction with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm currently stucked at a redirection issue for my PHP project. My Project has the following structure:

```
root
--config
--classes
--sites
--libs
--web
----assets
----index.php
--.htaccess
```

The main folder is the "web" Folder where all of my Code and Logics are loaded.
Is it possible to set a redirection in my .htaccess-File to load all the Content from the "/web" folder without displaying it in the URL ?

My .htaccess-File has following Content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web
<Files *.php>
    deny from all
</Files>
<Files "index.php">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ ?site=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ ?site=$1&slug1=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ ?site=$1&slug1=$2&slug2=$3 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: Sure that is possible. You do not want a redirection, but an internal rewrite. And you need to implement some conditions as exceptions most likely.

Comment: do you have a code example for me? i am not familiar with htaccess

Comment: Then I suggest that you take a look into the documentation of the tool you are using. As typical for OpenSource it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html